# Using Calabash query all does not give expected results

Tags: ios, automated-tests, calabash

As per https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/calabash/calabash-query-syntax/:

> By default Calabash will query only visible views (determined by a heuristic - not 100% bullet proof). If you want to change the behavior to query all views you simply prepend the modifier all.
>
> query("all button")
>
> query("all view marked:'something'")

using: `query("label marked: 'IN SEASON FRUITS & VEG' parent LTODepartmentsCellContentView")`
returns an empty array. This element is not visible in the iphone simulator until the user scrolls down. Using the all keyword in the query string, I expected would return the element hash search results.

i.e. `query("all label marked: 'IN SEASON FRUITS & VEG' parent LTODepartmentsCellContentView")` should return the element even though it's not visible.

Can anyone clarify the correct use of the `all` keyword in calabash `query` command?

Answer (score 2):

Calabash decides visibility based on certain heuristics. However, the view has to be in the view hierarchy to be able to be queried. It is very likely that your view is not added to the view hierarchy until it is scrolled to.

Comment: The `all` keyword is designed to reveal views that are hidden by the heuristic:  0 alpha, CGSize {0, 0}, and views that are visible to the eye, but whose midpoint is not visible to eye (e.g. behind another view or off the screen).